# kubectl proxy incorrectly uses kube-system default user

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Kubernetes cluster (v1.8.4) set up on Google Kubernetes Engine. I have properly set up and configured `kubectl` on my local machine, and I can use this command to successfully create and delete assets on Kubernetes.

However, when I run `kubectl proxy` to view the admin dashboard, I get errors indicating the connection is made with some kube-system default user that doesn't exist:

> configmaps is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default" cannot list configmaps at the cluster scope: Unknown user "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:default"

To verify, I have run

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster> --zone us-central1-f --project <project>
```

and my context is set correctly:

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                                       CLUSTER                                    AUTHINFO                                   NAMESPACE
*         gke_<project>_us-central1-f_<cluster>      gke_<project>_us central1-f_<cluster>      gke_<project>_us-central1-f_<cluster>   
          minikube                                   minikube                                   minikube
```

Shouldn't `kubectl proxy` use my google domain credentials when I access the dashboard?